# Mail can't delete old email address

Tags: mail.app, accounts

I recently picked up a used Macbook Pro with Lion installed.

There are no other accounts in the native Mail app except my new Gmail one.

However, when I send an email, the "Reply-to" address that the recipient sees is the email address of the previous owner.

I cannot find a way to remove this email address, it is not in the settings of my sole Gmail account.  It seems to be registered somewhere in the account info of the Mac.

Comment: Did you create a new account for yourself or are you using the account the previous owner used already?

Comment: I created a new account.

Comment: I bet patrix meant creating new user account on system (it's in System Preferences) i.e. not new mail account in Mail.

Answer (score 1):

Check the "me" card.  Open Address Book, go to the "Card" menu, and select "Go to my card".  Edit if required.  Restart Mail, and send yourself a test email.  Check the from address.

Also, I know you've already checked this, but please check again. In Mail.app, go to Preferences, Accounts, and *make sure* that the email address is set correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work : (